# Problem in creating multiple dataframe columns from a list in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using this list whose length is 1:

```
['Holding Investment Bid-market value value (£’000) (£’000) Total net assets (%) assets (%) Financials – 17.63% (31/03/21, – 17.55) Equity Investment Instruments – 0.92% 300000, Scottish 
Investment Trust 2220, 0.92, Financial Services – 6.97% 750000, Ashmore 2554, 1.06, 175000, Close Brothers 2704, 1.12, 175704, 1.12, 750000, IG Group 6034, 2.50, 750000, Ninety One 1928, 
0.80, 750928, 0.80, 2250, 000TP, ICAP 3591, 1.49, 2591, 1.49, Life Insurance – 4.67% 1750, 000Legal, & General 4919, 2.04, 200000, St James’s Place Capital 3014, 1.25, 200014, 1.25, 1300,
 000Standard, Life Aberdeen 3322, 1.38, 1322, 1.38, Non-Life Insurance – 2.41% 1000, Direct Line Insurance 3620, 1.50, 1000, 000Sabre, Insurance 2190, 0.91, 1190, 0.91, Real Estate Invest
ment Trusts – 2.66% 500000, British Land 2476, 1.02, 3500, 000NewRiver, Retail 2915, 1.21, 3915, 1.21, 125000, Workspace 1031, 0.43, 125031, 0.43, Total Financials 42518, 17.63, Technolog
y – 1.10% (31/03/21, – 1.65) Software & Computer Services – 1.10% 375000, Sage 2661, 1.10, Total Technology 2661, 1.10, Total value of investments 237016, 98.28, Net other assets 4143, 1.
72, Total net assets 241159, 100.00,']
```

I am trying to create a dataframe using this logic:

```
print(mylist)
print(len(mylist))
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    highlights_alt = list_highlights[i].split(',')
    print(highlights_alt)
    df = pd.DataFrame(highlights_alt)
    print(df.head())
```

In here I am looping through the length of the list and splitting on a delimiter(a comma here)
which gives me the list 'highlights_alt' as

```
['Holding Investment Bid-market value value (£’000) (£’000) Total net assets (%) assets (%) Financials – 17.63% (31/03/21', ' – 17.55) Equity Investment Instruments – 0.92% 300000', ' Sco
ttish Investment Trust 2220', ' 0.92', ' Financial Services – 6.97% 750000', ' Ashmore 2554', ' 1.06', ' 175000', ' Close Brothers 2704', ' 1.12', ' 175704', ' 1.12', ' 750000', ' IG Grou
p 6034', ' 2.50', ' 750000', ' Ninety One 1928', ' 0.80', ' 750928', ' 0.80', ' 2250', ' 000TP', ' ICAP 3591', ' 1.49', ' 2591', ' 1.49', ' Life Insurance – 4.67% 1750', ' 000Legal', ' & 
General 4919', ' 2.04', ' 200000', ' St James’s Place Capital 3014', ' 1.25', ' 200014', ' 1.25', ' 1300', ' 000Standard', ' Life Aberdeen 3322', ' 1.38', ' 1322', ' 1.38', ' Non-Life Ins
urance – 2.41% 1000', ' Direct Line Insurance 3620', ' 1.50', ' 1000', ' 000Sabre', ' Insurance 2190', ' 0.91', ' 1190', ' 0.91', ' Real Estate Investment Trusts – 2.66% 500000', ' Britis
h Land 2476', ' 1.02', ' 3500', ' 000NewRiver', ' Retail 2915', ' 1.21', ' 3915', ' 1.21', ' 125000', ' Workspace 1031', ' 0.43', ' 125031', ' 0.43', ' Total Financials 42518', ' 17.63', 
' Technology – 1.10% (31/03/21', ' – 1.65) Software & Computer Services – 1.10% 375000', ' Sage 2661', ' 1.10', ' Total Technology 2661', ' 1.10', ' Total value of investments 237016', ' 
98.28', ' Net other assets 4143', ' 1.72', ' Total net assets 241159', ' 100.00', '']
```

and my dataframe is seen as:

```
                                                   0
0  Holding Investment Bid-market value value (£’0...
1   – 17.55) Equity Investment Instruments – 0.92...
2                     Scottish Investment Trust 2220
3                                               0.92
4                  Financial Services – 6.97% 750000
```

I wanted to create 4 columns out of this list-`highlights_alt` where column1 would be `Holding`, column2 would be `Investment`, column3 would be `Bid-market value(£’000)` & column4 would be `Total net assets (%)` so that my final dataframe would look like this:

final df =

```
Holding                                Investment                Bid-market value(£’000)      Total net assets
Financials – 17.63% (31/03/21, – 17.55)
Equity Investment Instruments – 0.92%
300000                                 Scottish Investment Trust  2220                        0.92
```

[image: complete dataframe]
I tried creating column names in `pd.Dataframe(columns=['Holding', 'Investment', 'Bid-market value', 'Total net assets'])` itself however the respective values for it were not coming despite printing `df.head()`.

How can I create a dataframe successfully with all column values getting populated?

Comment: Where are yo getting the initial list from? Is it an actual list or perhps a json or xlm file?

Comment: its an actual list which is coming from code- the code extracts the list from a highlighted table from PDF.

Comment: OK, so say we're looking at the first column (Holding). What would be the data in it? Same for the next column (Investment), what would be the data? And same for the others.

Comment: @RobinSage you can check my updated question. I've added an image of my final dataframe.

Comment: I honestly don't see a way out of this. The list does not have a column/row pattern. I see, for instance, that Holdings column would have Equity Investment, Financial Services, Life Insurance, etc as rows, but the way I see it is that the list simply has item after item but not necessarily organized in column/row. If you could turn that orginal dataset into CSV format, it would be a lot easier to work it out. At least in my humble opinion...

Comment: oh, the original dataset is nothing but highlighted PDFs from there I am converting it to a list using pymupdf,fitz. not sure how to turn it in csv format. but thanks for giving me a few pointers

Comment: If you have a way to put it into excel, you can then save it as CSV. Once you import it into Python, it's smooth sail.

Comment: Or better yet, that data came from somewhere. Perhaps an API of some sort? Or maybe you can download it directly as CSV? Because having to type it all out manually kinda defeats the purpose of programming, eh?

Comment: @RobinSage to put it into an excel I am trying to put it in a data frame. Im having highlighted pdf, this pdf acts as an input file to my code wherein using pymupdf library I extract the highlighted portions from the pdf and paste it in a list, this list further I am trying to put it in data frame.